# Is autopy installable locally?

Tags: python, installation, autopy

i seem to have some trouble installing autopy.h

```
https://github.com/msanders/autopy/#introduction
```

i already tried the installation via git:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/msanders/autopy.git
$ cd autopy
$ python setup.py build
```

but i get the following error:

```
>python setup.py build 
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'color' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DNDEBUG=1 -DMM_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DUSE_X11 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/autopy-color-module.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/autopy-color-module.o -Wall -Wparentheses -Winline -Wbad-function-cast -Wdisabled-optimization -Wshadow
In file included from src/autopy-color-module.c:1:
src/autopy-color-module.h:5:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
In file included from src/autopy-color-module.c:1:
src/autopy-color-module.h:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘initcolor’
...
src/autopy-color-module.c:48: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

so

> src/autopy-color-module.h:5:20: error: Python.h: No such file or
>   directory

is missing. Is this because ubuntu hates me, or is it because the software is just not compilable from the git? Easy_install unfortunately needs access to `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/` which i don't have. I was hoping to import the library locally into my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have the development headers for python. Since you're on Ubuntu, just install the python-dev package:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: can i install that via synaptic, too? or even better locally?

Comment: synaptic is just a GUI around apt-get, so yes, you can. You can *only* install a package from apt-get locally, so I don't know what you mean by the second question.

Comment: src/keypress.c:10:35: error: X11/extensions/XTest.h: No such file or directory

Comment: how can i find out what else i am missing? now it seems to be xtest. thiss is really frustrating.

Comment: you need to install libxtst-dev - found by the first result when googling the error